Синонимизировать метки на тему Qt Creator
На тему Qt Creator'а есть две метки:

creator (11 вопросов) описания нет
qtcreator (559 вопросов) есть описание

Предлагаю синонимизировать (или объединить, потому что по названию не очень-то понятно, что это за метка?) creator -> qtcreator.
Хотя мне кажется, что лучше было бы qt-creator...

Я бы вообще заблокировал метку [creator] чтобы пресечь непонятность на корню

@andreymal блокировать метки могут только сотрудники почему-то. А они не очень расторопны в этих делах, поэтому проще запилить какой-то синоним, конечно. Как появлась метка "creator" вполне понятно: люди набирают "qt пробел creator" так и получается две метки вместо одной.

Удалил метку creator. Переименовал qtcreator в qt-creator по аналогии с enSO. Сделал последние две синонимами.
